# change select box style only using CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to make something like this, 
so i already can remove the border, but how to make it like this? with some arrow and custom font-size?

[select box css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwcen.png)

Comment: you can look for styles already created and import them in your document, like bootstrap for example got a couple of them that you can import Check this http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this**

```css
select.arrow {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
   border-right: 0px solid #999;
   border-left: 0px solid #999;
   border-top: 0px solid #999;
   width:200px;
   padding: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
   background: url(../images/pin-point.png) 95% 0 no-repeat; /* Add your image here*/
                        }
```

```html
<select class="arrow">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Please explain your code as what it does rather than simply saying try this.
To learn how to answer go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer